# Is there an elegant way to change the key of clojure map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I want to change the map:

```
{"a" 1 "b" 2}
```

to

```
{:a 1 :b 2}
```

how to do it in clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`keywordize-keys`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/keywordize-keys) function to do it.

```
user=> (clojure.walk/keywordize-keys {"a" 1 "b" 2})
;=> {:a 1 :b 2}

user=> (require '[clojure.walk :refer [keywordize-keys]])
;=> nil
user=> (keywordize-keys {"a" 1 "b" 2})
;=> {:a 1, :b 2}
```